# Why PyCharm highlight this piece of pandas code

Tags: pandas

I have simple code to 1) generate a new column based on the value of some existent columns in a data frame and 2) filter with `in` statement in a list comprehension.

I can actually run it successfully but PyCharm keeps highlighting the code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sex':['male','female','male'],
    'age':[10,20,30],
    'flag':['a b', 'b c', 'a f']
})

# problem 1: creating a new column based on other columns

df2 = df.assign(group = df.apply(lambda row: 
     'group_A' if row['sex'] == "male" and row['age'] < 25 else 'group_B', 
     axis = 1
))

# PyCharm： Expected type 'function', got '(row: Any) -> str' instead 

# problem 2: filtering with in statement and list comprehension

df['age'].values[
    (df.sex == 'male') & ['b' in x for x in df.flag]
][-1]

# PyCharm： Unexpected type(s): (List[bool]) Possible types: (bool) (int)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm linter failed in both cases. Because linting a dynamic language like Python is really hard.

Problem 1: PyCharm did not realize that a lambda is also a function

Problem 2: PyCharm sees the bitwise-and operator (&) and assumes both sides must be bool or int. It is not aware that & has been overridden to perform logical-and for numpy arrays and pandas Series.

You can ignore the warnings or [suppress them](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections). But I think a better is to rewrite your code.

```py
df2 = df.assign(
    group=np.where(df["sex"].eq("male") & df["age"].lt(25), "groupA", "groupB")
)

df["age"].values[
    df["sex"].eq("male") & df["flag"].str.contains("b")
]
```

PyCharm has one of the best linters of all Python IDEs in existence so if it fails, chances are your code made it hard to see the underlying logic.